# nssm service is downloading but not serving my web pages

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I'm deploying my node and express web application using nssm tool.

I've configured and installed my application as a service but when I navigate to

http://localhost:3000 the ./bin/wwww file is being downloaded instead of serving it.

My application is Node and Express. My startup file is app.js. I'm able to launch the application with the commands

```
npm start
```

or simply 
    nodemon 
but cannot run the application using nssm. Can anyone help me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What file extension is being downloaded if I may ask? and do you use `Content-Disposition` header?

Comment: the bin/www file is being downloaded. There is no extension. I'm not sure about the header. Where is it set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've switched to a different method.

qckwinsvc is simple and easy to use. I pointed the script path to my appdir\bin\www for this to work.